# Using Websphere MQ QueueDepth with a clustered queue

Tags: c#, message-queue, ibm-mq

I have a C# application that needs to periodically check the depth of a queue, which then potentially determines some behaviors for new inbound messages.  (Essentially, when we have a high depth in the queue for an extended period and some other qualifications are met, some messages need to be set to a higher priority level to ensure they're processed promptly.)

My code worked fine on the development side, but then when it went to QA, it started failing with CompCode: 1, Reason: 2068.  My research seems to indicate that this means the queue in question is clustered in the QA environment, and that my request is invalid for a clustered queue.

I'm not very experienced with Websphere interface, so I'm hoping somebody can help me figure out how to do this.

Here's the way I'm calling it now:

```
try
{
    MQQueueManager mqManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManager);
    MQQueue mqQueue = mqManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
    int depth = mqQueue.CurrentDepth;
    mqQueue.Close();
    mqManager.Disconnect();
    return depth;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //there's lots of irrelevant handling here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a local instance of the cluster queue present in the queue manager to which your application is connecting to inquire queue depth. If no local instance is present, then few attributes can be inquired as documented [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101840_.htm?lang=en) - look under the #4 of Usage notes.

From v701 onwards MQ ships cluster queue monitoring utility [AMQSCLM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024630_.htm?lang=en) that can monitor cluster queues and route the messages to other cluster queues if the messages are not being consumed. You may to have a look at this utility. Sample code is available for the utility, so you customize it.

Comment: Thank you.  I discussed with the server manager and we determined that there was no reason for the queue to be clustered anyway, so we fixed it that way.